# Why do I get a 403 when hitting a localhost iisexpress site hosted on a VM

Tags: windows, iis-express, parallels

So before I start, I know how to open up IISExpress to the network, there's plenty of articles about this, [I even wrote one](http://georgemauer.net/2013/10/09/open-iis-to-the-network). However, these approaches do have limitations - most notably the need to add bindings which I've found to be hit-or-miss and worse, breaks any code that does things based on hostname.

I am on OsX running Windows 10 inside of Parallels and earlier this week I thought I should try to get localhost forwarded into the VM in the same way that I can do with docker containers.

I got really close, but I cannot figure out the last step. Here is what I did and what I am seeing:

1. I temporarily disabled my firewall on Windows
2. I forwarded the correct port (44300 in this case) to the guest VM and rebooted it.
3. I ran iisexpress through the command line so that I can see the full log (I tried through visual studio as well)

What I'm seeing is that when I hit `localhost:44300` from inside the VM, my site loads fine and all sorts of things are logged.

But when I hit it from the host I'm getting

> HTTP Error 403. The request URL is forbidden.

There is nothing logged by iisexpress in this scenario.

However, I know that the request is in *some manner* getting through since if I stop iisexpress and head to `localhost:44300` again on the host, I get the standard

> localhost refused to connect. ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

The fact that iisexpress is or is not listening on that port *is* cascading up to the host VM therefore, but nothing else is getting through.

So I'm a bit at a loss - it almost looks kinda like a binding thing, but as far as iisexpress knows, due to the port forwarding, wouldn't this request *be* coming from `localhost`? How can it tell if it is not? Even that sounds unlikely due to the lack of log messages. Also I never see anything pop up in fiddler.

What I wonder instead if there might be some *yet other* windows component that sees something bound to 44300, sees an request coming over the network stack, and shuts it down. Is that a thing?

Comment: With a tool like Jexus Manager https://docs.jexusmanager.com/, you should be able to enable Failed Request Tracing and IIS logs to see what 403 you get exactly, https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/943891/the-http-status-code-in-iis-7-0-iis-7-5-and-iis-8-0

Comment: @LexLi the question is about iis express

Comment: What makes you feel that I was not talking about IIS Express?

Comment: Just that the comment specifically mentioned IIS and so did the article. I'll check out how it might work with iisexpress

Comment: It is not "might" but "must". Microsoft fails to update the docs, though.

Comment: Well that was pointless. After downloading the mis and running the installer for Jesus, I get an app that doesn't run and Windows doesn't know how to open it.